# How to update mysql cols with comparison

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

I have this table:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| Field          | Type         |
+----------------+--------------+
| id             | int(10)      |
| confirm        | int(5)       |
| confirm_hold   | int(5)       |
| tmp            | int(6)       |
+----------------+--------------+
```

and have a some problem.

How can UPDATE some row.
For example:

```
UPDATE `table` IF(`tmp` > 0, SET `confirm_hold`=123, SET `confirm`=123);
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE `table` SET `confirm_hold` = IF(`tmp` > 0, 123, `confirm_hold`),  `confirm` = IF(`tmp` <= 0, 123, `confirm`)
```

Comment: you can use one if statment for every column , if you update two columns then you use 2 if

Comment: I absolutely love how I was the first to answer this correctly, then you changed your `different` answer (I remember seeing the code line being way shorter than the current) to be identical to mine and got all the points just because you have more reputation. Not cool.

Answer (score 2):

Use function [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) instead:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `confirm_hold` = IF(`tmp` > 0, 123, `confirm_hold`), 
                   `confirm` = IF(`tmp` <= 0, 123, `confirm`)
```